# ReactJS - Get children elements in the parent and looping to execute a method of each child

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm a beginner of ReactJS and I have a simple question...

I could capture all children elements and loop those elements in the parent?
I see a lot of examples to modify a single child element triggering a method.

Basically, I have a test page, here I have a section of one unique selection. 
I want to implement a button (in the parent) to help me to validate if the answers are correct or wrong (all at once).

Here is the code:

https://mbv401920150.github.io/Math/code.js

Where is the actual page:

https://mbv401920150.github.io/Math

Any comment will be welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so you may be looking at this to be a lot more difficult than it needs to be :)

The simplest way to handle this scenario, and maybe even clean up your code (It was a lot so I just skimmed XD ) is to create an array of each question and store it seperately in `questionList.js` or something:

```
export const questions = [
    {
        key: "q1",
        answer: "a",
        options: {},
    }
}
```

For each of these questions you store whatever information you need access to (I'm not sure what you need) the options are endless.

Next you set your state on the parent component:

```
this.state = {
    answers: []
}
```

Now what this will do is track the answers as the user inputs them into each component.

So now you put it all together in a really neat way, using the `questionList` you can map through each question to render it out and use onChange to pass back the values:

```
{questionList.map(question => {
        return (
            <Question 
                onChange={(e) => this.handleQuestionAnswered(question, e) 
                data={question}
            />
        )
    })    
}
```

Where `this.handleQuestionAnswered()` takes the question and the answer and updates the state as such:

```
this.setState(prevState => {
    const newAnswers = prevState.answers;
    newAnswers[question.key] = e.target.value;
    return {
        answers: newAnswers,
    }
});
```

Then once your validation is triggered you can loop through the answers using the keys and validate each one :)

This could be a much more lengthy explanation but I hope it gives you a better direction... React is all about finding the best ways to do things easy :D

Answer (score 1):

A good practice is not to access child components, but request data from them. Also it is nice to have a single source of trust, means each piece of your data should be in one exact place.

I your case:

1. Keep data about checked options in your parent component (the one that contains a submit button and will check the answers)
2. Pass a callback to child components through which they will inform the parent if something have changed

Note that child components should not contain state about what was selected, you have to pass this data from the parent component.